# Lilypond - '\on-the-fly #print-page-number-check-first' not working in version 2.24.1 anymore

Tags: lilypond

**I used the following code for page numbering and copyright formatting in** `lilypond --version 2.20.0`:

```
pagenumcol = \markup {
  \column {
    \vspace #0.5
    \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
  }
}

copyrightcol = "My Copyright file"

\paper {
  ragged-right = ##f
  page-breaking = #ly:page-turn-breaking

  oddHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  evenHeaderMarkup = \markup \null

  oddFooterMarkup = \markup {
    \copyrightcol
    \on-the-fly #print-page-number-check-first
    \pagenumcol
  }

  evenFooterMarkup = \markup {
    \on-the-fly #print-page-number-check-first
    \pagenumcol
    \copyrightcol
  }
}
```

**Now with** `lilypond --version 2.24.1` **I get the following error:**

```
GNU LilyPond 2.24.1 (running Guile 2.2)
Processing `First-Piano-two-hand-Exercises.ly'
Parsing...
./global-files/paper.ily:19:18: error: Guile signaled an error for the expression beginning here
    \on-the-fly #
                 print-page-number-check-first
Unbound variable: print-page-number-check-first
./global-files/paper.ily:19:17: error: wrong type for argument 1.  Expecting procedure, found #<unspecified>
    \on-the-fly 
                #print-page-number-check-first
ERROR: In procedure ly:parse-file:
In procedure reverse!: Wrong type argument in position 1: (#<unspecified> . #f)
```

**Does anyone know how to fix this?** A simple `convert-ly` run did not do :-(

Comment: I don't know to use these commands, but I remember it said something about `\on-the-fly` being depreciated on the [2.24 Changes page](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/changes/).

Comment: YEA, THX @ElementsinSpace it claims to use `\if` or `\unless` instead of `\on-the-fly`, both not working with `#print-page-number-check-first`. Guess the last one has to be replaced too... :-/

Comment: @nath Please check that you ran `convert-ly` correctly. For me, it converts this code to correct LilyPond 2.24 code.

Comment: THX @jeanas  - yea it does! I forgot adding a `\version NUMBER`!!! My `paper-file` is an inlcuded `.ily` file that does not have a version number by default. Can `convert-ly` follow files linked with the `\include` command?

Comment: Currently, it cannot. You should either put `\version` numbers in all included files (which I would recommend), or run `convert-ly` with `--from 2.20.0` to override the `\version` detection logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some further reading in the [documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/custom-layout-for-headers-and-footers.de.html) and I found this:

```
\paper {
  print-page-number = ##t
  print-first-page-number = ##t
  oddHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  evenHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  oddFooterMarkup = \markup {
    \fill-line {
      \if \should-print-page-number
      \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
    }
  }
  evenFooterMarkup = \oddFooterMarkup
}
```

**I changed my code by replacing `\on-the-fly #print-page-number-check-first` with `\if \should-print-page-number`:**

```
pagenumcol = \markup {
  \column {
    \vspace #0.5
    \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
  }
}

copyrightcol = "My Copyright file"

\paper {
  ragged-right = ##f
  page-breaking = #ly:page-turn-breaking

  oddHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  evenHeaderMarkup = \markup \null

  oddFooterMarkup = \markup {
    \copyrightcol
    \if \should-print-page-number
    \pagenumcol
  }
  
  evenFooterMarkup = \markup {
    \if \should-print-page-number
    \pagenumcol
    \copyrightcol
  }
}
```

***It compiles without errors :-)***